# Embedding video for Chrome without NPAPI support

Tags: google-chrome, video, plugins

Im building a site where video will be stream from mp4/m4v files on the server.

I am having trouble making this work in Chrome 47, evidently due to lack of NPAPI support.

Here are some variations of code I have tried and the results:

```
<video controls> 
    <param name="video" value="true" />
    <source src="app/files/s1e1.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="app/files/s1e1.m4v" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Result: I get a javascript error frame with an message reading "This plugin is not supported"

```
<object width="100%" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="app/files/s1e1.m4v"/
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <embed width="100%" height="360" src="app/files/s1e1.m4v" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
</object>
```

Result: The player renders and seems to load the file evidenced by the correct video length being displayed in the player, but video does not play when I hit the play button.

Either method works perfectly in Safari.

Which method is best for cross-browser support?

Comment: It looks like your "Result" lines are backward; <object> is a plugin (and thus not supported in Chrome, and will give the plugin error message), whereas <video> is standards-based.

Comment: no, definitely not the case. I know its strange. but <video> definitely gives the error, and <object> loads the player but content doesnt play. I can fathom who <video> is not working in chrome of all things